# SSL page redirecting to SSL page on another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-6

My company wants to change domain names.

Requests to http://ServerA/folder/page.aspx need to go to http://ServerB/folder/page.aspx.
I can do most of the redirection in IIS and it works fine.

I have a concern that I don't seem to have the ability to test.  Are there any problems/concerns form using the same technique for SSL pages?  That is:  to .

Using C#/ASP.net/ISS6 (I think)/Windows Server 2003

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems it didn't let you post 2 urls anyway, both urls are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems, no real security issues, but the browser will throw up a notification that the user is being redirected, and may require them to accept another certificate, or, if you're using the same certificate, may make snide little comments about the certificate being valid for servera.domain.com not serverb.domain.com.

If I were you, I'd try to remove the SSL from the original domain name, just to remove the possibility of having multiple SSL popups around to alarm your users.

Answer (score 1):

if you have "bought" ssl certificates this will work without any warning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I wish I could mark them both correct.